# How to loop and click all icons to download files with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, browser-automation

Update 15/11/2023:

Hi,

able to sovle the pdf download issues after I revise the code by re-lookup the pdf_links at the end of the loop as follow:

```
pdf_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as PDF"]')

for i in range(len(pdf_links)):
    # print(pdf_links[i])
    
    pdf_links[i].click()
    select_all_box = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@controlid="selectAll"]/following-sibling::span')))
    select_all_box.click()
    submit_select_button = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@label="Submit"]'))).click()
    download_button = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@label="Download"]'))).click()

    WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as PDF"]')))
    
    pdf_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as PDF"]')
```

However, another question coming up about the excel download is that the codes run ok with time.sleep() but not with WebDriverWait

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as Excel"]')))

excel_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as Excel"]')

for i in range(len(excel_links)):
    print(excel_links[i])

    excel_links[i].click()
    time.sleep(3)
    # WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as Excel"]')))
    
    excel_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as Excel"]')
```

When I use the WebdriverWait line instead of time.sleep() it throw me the following error:

[image: WebDriverWait behaviour]

[image: Excel Dom]

Your comments will be helpful.

====================================================================

hi I'm trying to loop through and click all icons to download the pdf/excel files. Its an intranet site so all I can provide are only screenshots with html codes.

I've spent 3 to 4 hours each day for the past 3 days but not having any success yet. You advise will be appreciated.

Basically there are 2 icons per row, 1 for pdf and the other for excel, and there are 50 rows per page.

[image: 2 icons per row]

The DOM for pdf as follow:

[image: DOM for Excel & PDF]

When click the pdf icon it brings the popup as follow

[image: form selection]

With the following DOM:

[image: selecion check box]

Then I will select all then submit to bring the download button

[image]

And the DOM for download button
[image: download button]

The codes I have so far to download the pdfs as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as PDF"]')))
pdf_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as PDF"]')

for pdf in pdf_links:
    pdf.click()
    select_all_box = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[@class="_checkmark_17ala_27"]')))
    select_all_box.click()
    submit_select_button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@label="Submit"]'))).click()
    download_button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@label="Download"]'))).click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

When I run the code it only downloads the first pdf file, then throw me an "NoSuchElementException"

[image: exception details]

The download excel operation is relatively easier as the excel would be automatically downloaded once the icon is clicked.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as Excel"]')))

excel_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@title="Download as Excel"]')

for excel in excel_links:
    excel.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Similar with the codes for pdf it only downlaod the first excel in the webpage and give me an "NoSuchElementException":

[image: No such element exception]

Comment: You are targeting the span instead of the checkbox... try with XPATH: //input[@controlid="selectAll"]  After you click the submit button you'll probably have a stale DOM.  You may need to re-get the "download" button after clicking that.  (Avoid doing any actions that update the dom during iteration of webelement reference array.)

Comment: @pcalkins, would you please elaborate a little on "Avoid doing any actions that update the dom during iteration of webelement reference array", and how I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: For instance, a click action... after sending the click, the DOM may update via Javascript.  If that happens while looping through the array, all the next iterations will be stale.  In your case that might happen while iterating "pdf_links" after clicking the submit button?